# Create form from template "Error encounter: Unknown macro showForm

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been reading "Google Script" and the book goes through several uses for Google Apps script and walks you through building an app.

I've gone through a section for about creating forms dynamically from templates and I'm running into an issue I can't get around. When accessing the published URL, it returns "Error Encountered: Unknown macro showForm" What puzzles me is I've tried using firebug in mozilla and debug in the script editor but no errors are identified.  Anyone able to help point out where I should be looking or a direction to help troubleshoot to get this going
?

Here is the Code.  Its broken into three pieces.  Code.gs, GS Objecgts.js, and Documents API.js

**CODE.GS**

```
    var templateFolderId = '<<Enter Folder ID>>';

function doGet(e){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Template Creator');

  //What this app is about
  var grid = app.createGrid(6, 2).setId('grid').setCellPadding(5);
  app.add(grid);

  grid.setWidget(0,0, app.createLabel("This App will allow you to create a form from"+
                                 " a template in Google Docs."));

  //create UI here
  // File Chooser  
  var fileChooser = app.createListBox().setName('fileChooser').setId('fileChooser')
                   .addChangeHandler(app.createServerChangeHandler('showForm')  
                   .addCallbackElement(grid)); 
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, fileChooser);



  //set the file Names in the listBox by calling on the DocsList service
  fileChooser.addItem('Choose Template');
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById(templateFolderId).getFiles();
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fileChooser.addItem(files[i].getName());
  }



  // Submit the form button  
  var button = app.createButton('Submit').setId('button')
              .addClickHandler(app.createServerClickHandler('createDoc')
                              .addCallbackElement(grid))
              .setVisible(false);

  grid.setWidget(4, 0, button);


  /*
  *  @returns body text from doc
  */
function getTemplateText(fileName){
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById(templateFolderId).getFiles();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  if (fileName == files[i].getName()){  
     var text =  DOCS_LIST_API.GdocToFormat(files[i].getId(), 'txt');
    return text.getContentText();
      }  
    }       
}

  // function returns an array of unique form keys
function createKeys(templateFile){
  var templateTxt = getTemplateText(templateFile); 
  var templateVars = templateTxt.match(/\{\%[^\%]+\%\}/g);
  var templateKeys = [];
  var oneEach = "";
  for (var i in templateVars) {
    var keyObject = {};
    keyObject.text = templateVars[i].replace(/\{\%|\%\}/g, '');
    keyObject.id = camelString(templateVars[i]);
    if (oneEach.match(keyObject.text) == null){                 
      templateKeys.push(keyObject);  
    }
    oneEach += " " + keyObject.text;
  }   
  return templateKeys;
}

  function showForm(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable();
  var keys = createKeys(e.parameter.fileChooser);

    for (var i in keys) {
    var text = (keys[i].text);

    if(/^instruction/i.test(text)){       
  flexTable.setWidget(parseInt(i),0,app
                      .createLabel(text.substring(text.indexOf(':')+1)));      
    }else{
      var questionPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
      flexTable.setWidget(parseInt(i),0,questionPanel);    
      questionPanel.add(app.createLabel(text).setWidth('100px'));
      questionPanel.add(app.createTextBox().setName(keys[i].id));  
    }
  }

    flexTable.setWidget(keys.length+1,0,app.createLabel('________'));
  flexTable.setWidget(keys.length+2,0, app.createHorizontalPanel()
                                  .add(app.createLabel('Output file name: ').setWidth('100px'))
                                  .add(app.createTextBox()
                                        .setName('outputFile').setWidth('200px')
                                        .setValue('Copy of '+ e.parameter.fileChooser)));
  flexTable.setWidget(keys.length+3,0, app.createHorizontalPanel()
                                  .add(app.createLabel('Google Email: ').setWidth('100px'))
                                  .add(app.createTextBox()
                                        .setName('email').setWidth('200px')));

    app.getElementById('button').setVisible(true);        
  app.getElementById('grid').setWidget(3,0, flexTable);
  return app;  
}

  function createDoc(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var keys = createKeys(e.parameter.fileChooser);
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById(templateFolderId).getFiles();

for (var i in files) {
  if (e.parameter.fileChooser == files[i].getName()){   
    var copyId = files[i].makeCopy(e.parameter.outputFile).getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
    var copy = doc.getActiveSection();
    for (var i in keys) {
      var text = keys[i].text;    
      if(/^instruction/i.test(text)){ 
        if (copy.findText(keys[i].text) != null)
          copy.findText(keys[i].text).getElement().removeFromParent();
      }else{
        copy.replaceText('{%'+keys[i].text+'%}', e.parameter[keys[i].id]);
      }        
    }
    doc.saveAndClose();   
    doc.addEditor(e.parameter.email); 
     }
   }

app.getElementById('grid').setWidget(3,0, app.createAnchor('Open your Document', 
doc.getUrl())
                                  .setStyleAttribute('font-size', '18px'));
  app.getElementById('button').setVisible(false); 
  app.getElementById('fileChooser').setItemSelected(0, true);

  return app;  
}

  return app;  
}
```

**GS Objects.gs**

```
/*
   ObjService

   Copyright (c) 2011 James Ferreira

   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
*/

/**
 * ObjService
 * @author James Ferriera
 * @documentation http://goo.gl/JdEHW
 *
 * Changes an object like e.parameter into a 2D array useful in 
 * writting to a spreadsheet with using the .setValues method
 *
 * @param   {Array}   headers    [header, header, ...] 
 * @param   {Array}   objValues  [{key:value, ...}, ...]
 * @returns {Array}              [[value, value, ...], ...]
 */
function objectToArray(headers, objValues){
  var values = [];  
  var headers = camelArray(headers);  
  for (var j=0; j < objValues.length; j++){
var rowValues = [];
for (var i=0; i < headers.length; i++){
  rowValues.push(objValues[j][headers[i]]);
}  
values.push(rowValues);
  } 
  return values;
}


/**
 * Changes a range array often returned from .getValues() into an 
 * array of objects with key value pairs.
 * The first element in the array is used as the keys (headers)
 *
 * @param   {Array}   range   [[key, key, ...],[value, value, ...]] 
 * @returns {Array}           [{key:value, ...}, ...] 
 */
function rangeToObjects(range){
  var headers = range[0];
   var values = range;
  var rowObjects = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
    var row = new Object();
    row.rowNum = i;
    for (var j in headers){
      row[camelString(headers[j])] = values[i][j];
    }
   rowObjects.push(row); 
  }   
  return rowObjects;
}

/**
     * Changes a range array into an array of objects with key value pairs
 *
 * @params  {array}    headers  [key, key, ...]
 * @params  {array}    values    [[value, value, ...], ...]
 * @returns {array}    [{key:value, ...}, ...]  
 */
function splitRangesToObjects(headers, values){
  var rowObjects = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
    var row = new Object();
    row.rowNum = i;
    for (var j in headers){
      row[camelString(headers[j])] = values[i][j];
    }
   rowObjects.push(row); 
  }   
  return rowObjects;
}



/**
 * Removes special characters from strings in an array
     * Commonly know as a camelCase, 
 * Examples:
 *   "First Name" -> "firstName"
 *   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
 *   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
 * @params  {array} headers   [string, string, ...]
 * @returns {array}           camelCase 
 */
function camelArray(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = camelString(headers[i]);
    if (key.length > 0) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}    


/**
 * Removes special characters from a string
 * Commonly know as a camelCase, 
 * Examples:
 *   "First Name" -> "firstName"
     *   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
 *   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
 * @params  {string}  header   string
 * @returns {string}           camelCase 
 */
function camelString(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
  continue;
   }
if (!isAlnum_(letter)) {
  continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit_(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

function isCellEmpty_(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}
function isAlnum_(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit_(char);
}
function isDigit_(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

**Documents API.gs**

```
    /*
*  Private for OAuth
*  @ returns OAuth headers 
*/
var DOCS_LIST_API = {};

DOCS_LIST_API.googleOAuth = function() {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService('google');
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/"+
         "OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://docs.google.com/feeds/");
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:'google', oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}

/*
*  @ args     docID  String   the id for a Google Document
*  @ args     format String   can be, "txt", "odt", "pdf", "html", "rtf", "doc", "png", 
"zip"
*  @ returns  blob 
*
*/
DOCS_LIST_API.GdocToFormat = function(docID, format){
  var fetchArgs = DOCS_LIST_API.googleOAuth();   
  fetchArgs.headers = { "GData-Version": "3.0" };
  fetchArgs.method = 'get';
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id='+
                       docID+'&exportFormat='+format+'&format='+format; 
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs); 
}

  // Run it twice  
function doOAuth(){
  try{
    DOCS_LIST_API.GdocToFormat();
  }catch(e){
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that firebug won't show any errors, since Google Apps Script code is run server side, not in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems there is an error in code.gs

the "logical" version should be like this : (copy & paste in your script editor)

```
   var templateFolderId = '<<Enter Folder ID>>';

function doGet(e){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Template Creator');

  //What this app is about
  var grid = app.createGrid(6, 2).setId('grid').setCellPadding(5);
  app.add(grid);

  grid.setWidget(0,0, app.createLabel("This App will allow you to create a form from"+
                                 " a template in Google Docs."));

  //create UI here
  // File Chooser  
  var fileChooser = app.createListBox().setName('fileChooser').setId('fileChooser')
                   .addChangeHandler(app.createServerChangeHandler('showForm')  
                   .addCallbackElement(grid)); 
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, fileChooser);



  //set the file Names in the listBox by calling on the DocsList service
  fileChooser.addItem('Choose Template');
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById(templateFolderId).getFiles();
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fileChooser.addItem(files[i].getName());
  }



  // Submit the form button  
  var button = app.createButton('Submit').setId('button')
              .addClickHandler(app.createServerClickHandler('createDoc')
                              .addCallbackElement(grid))
              .setVisible(false);

  grid.setWidget(4, 0, button);

return app
  }
  /*
  *  @returns body text from doc
  */
function getTemplateText(fileName){
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById(templateFolderId).getFiles();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  if (fileName == files[i].getName()){  
     var text =  DOCS_LIST_API.GdocToFormat(files[i].getId(), 'txt');
    return text.getContentText();
      }  
    }       
}

  // function returns an array of unique form keys
function createKeys(templateFile){
  var templateTxt = getTemplateText(templateFile); 
  var templateVars = templateTxt.match(/\{\%[^\%]+\%\}/g);
  var templateKeys = [];
  var oneEach = "";
  for (var i in templateVars) {
    var keyObject = {};
    keyObject.text = templateVars[i].replace(/\{\%|\%\}/g, '');
    keyObject.id = camelString(templateVars[i]);
    if (oneEach.match(keyObject.text) == null){                 
      templateKeys.push(keyObject);  
    }
    oneEach += " " + keyObject.text;
  }   
  return templateKeys;
}

  function showForm(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable();
  var keys = createKeys(e.parameter.fileChooser);

    for (var i in keys) {
    var text = (keys[i].text);

    if(/^instruction/i.test(text)){       
  flexTable.setWidget(parseInt(i),0,app
                      .createLabel(text.substring(text.indexOf(':')+1)));      
    }else{
      var questionPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
      flexTable.setWidget(parseInt(i),0,questionPanel);    
      questionPanel.add(app.createLabel(text).setWidth('100px'));
      questionPanel.add(app.createTextBox().setName(keys[i].id));  
    }
  }

    flexTable.setWidget(keys.length+1,0,app.createLabel('________'));
  flexTable.setWidget(keys.length+2,0, app.createHorizontalPanel()
                                  .add(app.createLabel('Output file name: ').setWidth('100px'))
                                  .add(app.createTextBox()
                                        .setName('outputFile').setWidth('200px')
                                        .setValue('Copy of '+ e.parameter.fileChooser)));
  flexTable.setWidget(keys.length+3,0, app.createHorizontalPanel()
                                  .add(app.createLabel('Google Email: ').setWidth('100px'))
                                  .add(app.createTextBox()
                                        .setName('email').setWidth('200px')));

    app.getElementById('button').setVisible(true);        
  app.getElementById('grid').setWidget(3,0, flexTable);
  return app;  
}

  function createDoc(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var keys = createKeys(e.parameter.fileChooser);
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById(templateFolderId).getFiles();

for (var i in files) {
  if (e.parameter.fileChooser == files[i].getName()){   
    var copyId = files[i].makeCopy(e.parameter.outputFile).getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
    var copy = doc.getActiveSection();
    for (var i in keys) {
      var text = keys[i].text;    
      if(/^instruction/i.test(text)){ 
        if (copy.findText(keys[i].text) != null)
          copy.findText(keys[i].text).getElement().removeFromParent();
      }else{
        copy.replaceText('{%'+keys[i].text+'%}', e.parameter[keys[i].id]);
      }        
    }
    doc.saveAndClose();   
    doc.addEditor(e.parameter.email); 
     }
   }

app.getElementById('grid').setWidget(3,0, app.createAnchor('Open your Document', 
doc.getUrl())
                                  .setStyleAttribute('font-size', '18px'));
  app.getElementById('button').setVisible(false); 
  app.getElementById('fileChooser').setItemSelected(0, true);

  return app;  
}
```

EDIT : after saving, use this feature to test :[image]

Comment: Serge..Thanks for the reply.. i've updated my Code.gs with you reply, but after saving and republishing the app. I copy the URL into a new browser and the same error comes up..

Comment: in your script editor does "showform" appear along with doGet etc... ?

Comment: Also when you save and re-publish are you sure you are calling the right version ?

Comment: see last edit ;-) I tested the code here and it works as expected.